# Mount cifs Network Drive: write permissions and chown

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, chown, cifs

I have access to a cifs network drive. When I mount it under my OSX machine, I can read and write from and to it.

When I mount the drive in ubuntu, using:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD} //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

I am not able to write to the network drive, but I can read from it.
I have checked the permissions and owner of the mount folder, they look like:

```
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    0 Nov 12  2010 Mounted_folder
```

I cannot change the owner, because I get the error:

```
chown: changing ownership of `/Volumes/Mounted_folder': Not a directory
```

When I descend deeper into the network drive, and change the ownership there, I get the error that I have no permission to change the folder´s owner.

What should I do to activate my write permission?

Comment: Is the file system listed in /etc/fstab? If so, what options does the entry have?

Comment: You can also use the `noperm` mount option similarly stated in my answer to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375523/16287. This will give **all** users read and write access to the CIFS mount.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You are mounting the CIFS share as root (because you used `sudo`), so you cannot write as normal user. If your Linux Distribution and its kernel are recent enough that you could mount the network share as a normal user (but under a folder that the user own), you will have the proper credentials to write file (e.g. mount the shared folder somewhere under your home directory, like for instance `$HOME/netshare/`. Obviously, you would need to create the folder before mounting it).

An alternative is to specify the user and group ID that the mounted network share should used, this would allow that particular user and potentially group to write to the share. Add the following [options to your mount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.cifs.8.html#contenttoc3): `uid=<user>,gid=<group>` and replace `<user>` and `<group>` respectively by your own user and default group, which you can find automatically with the `id` command.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

If the server is sending ownership information, you may need to add the `forceuid` and `forcegid` options.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),forceuid,forcegid, //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

Comment: it worked for me! But we should add that if the shared folder is in a PC with a login domain you should add the option `domain`. Something like this: `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},dom=${DOMAIN}, uid=<user>,gid=<group> //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu` In fact the domain can go in the "username" option, but remember that you have to use `/` instead of `\`, like `username=DOMAIN/user.name`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. :-) One might need to specify the domain or workgroup (for older Windows version) via the "domain=" option or via the username, that's a good point. And sometimes it is even necessary to specify the encryption scheme or the CIFS version to be used. But all this was not part of this question, so I left it aside. :-)

Comment: This is just what I needed. I had an entry in /etc/fstab to auto mount the network drive on startup. I could not write to the mount so I added ,uid=<myUserID> for a line that looks like this: `//192.168.1.7/public /colmustang                          cifs    username=<uname>,password=<upassword>,uid=<myUserID> 0 0`

Comment: One question. Why do we specify user two times? First we have `username=...` and then `uid=...`? If I have created a new user like `useradd -s/bin/bash -m -g users dijak` on host, should I use `gid=users`?

Comment: @71GA `username` is the remote login to use for authentication. The `uid` is the local user ID you want to nap all files/folders. So the username is decoupled from the uid, the username is the remote user login while the uid is your local user id. Note that it could be the same thing if your server is Samba and you use an LDAP or other centralized account on both client and server :-).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaination! It is very helpfull and I must say I respect that people like you are willing to help on the forums. For me samba works best if I create a new user, put a shared folder in it's home directory and then create a symbolic link to this folder in my main user's home directory. If I put shared folder anywhere outside of the new user's home directory I experienced lots of troubles.

Comment: FYI [jstricker's edit suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/191200) is being [discussed on meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4433/clarification-on-rejected-edit).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, even with uid,gid,forceuid and forcegid it’s still read-only.

Comment: @Soonts This might be due to other problems. We could open a chat if you want to try helping. One useful thing could be to check your system log message (the `message` or `syslog` file under `/var/log/`, or using `journalctl`) and the print of the command `mount -t cifs`.

Comment: @Gilles how I can automatically fetch the `uid` and `gid`? so that I don't have to manually set it everytime I mount a server?

Comment: @Tak Good question. See the edited answer.

Comment: @Gilles thank you. And what if I wanted to do this in the /etc/fstab file?

Comment: @Gilles  I’ve posted a question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/457921/85865  but the answer provided didn’t address the question to automatically fetch the uid and gid

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned `file_mode` and `dir_mode`, which can be used (in conjunction with the other options discussed) to fine-tune access control in this and similar scenarios.

Comment: @BenJohnson the files were owned by `root:root`. So you could add your user to the root group and set permissions for the group to be writable or you can set the `other` as writable. Both solutions are far from ideal and I am not recommending them. Hence I do not mention file and dir mode.

Comment: @Huygens about `If the server is sending ownership information` - How know if the server is sending that info or not?.

Answer (score 39):

I tested the following command successfully:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=[username],password=[password],uid=1001,gid=1001 //172.16.148.2/dfsgob01 /home/ususario/Documentos/benz-win
```

Comment: Use "id -u <user>" and "id -g <user> to get the uid and gid respectively.

Comment: Note that you can use the user name directly as documented in `man mount.cifs`

Comment: To avoid writing the password alongside the command just omit the password option during the call - a prompt will then ask for it so it can be typed in invisibly.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this (if you can accept the security risks) is to use CIFS's [`noperm`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) option to allow **all** users to read and write to the CIFS mount.

I haven't tested this command, but I believe this would work:

```
sudo mount \
  -t cifs \
  -o noperm \
  //server-address/folder \
  /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

(you can also add this option via the `fstab` file)

Comment: This worked like a charm!