# How to make a cifs/smb mount ignore umask?

Tags: permissions, mount, cifs, umask, smb

I have a cifs mount that is mounted from `/etc/fstab`. But I would quite like creation of files/dirs on that share to ignore my umask. Is that possible? It seems that cifs does not support the `umask=000` option (source: `man mount.cifs`).

My current best option is to set my system-wide umask to 000, but I'd rather not do this as I'd like to keep the local machine a bit more locked down. The silly thing is that my previous NAS did this fine, so maybe it's a server-side change that's required?

Comment: How about the `file_mode` and `dir_mode` options?

Comment: From what I understand, this only applies to existing files, if the server does not support the CIFS Unix extensions (which it seems mine did).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in my question, it was a server-side change that needed making. I added these lines to `/etc/smb.conf` on the server:

```
create mask = 0666
force create mode = 0666
directory mask = 0777
force directory mode = 0777
```

And now it works fabulously.

Answer (score 6):

The `noperm` `fstab` option allows **all** users to read and write to the CIFS mount (which is what `umask=000` would have done if it was supported by `mount.cifs`).

Example line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
\\computer\UNC\path  /mnt/path  cifs  auto,rw,user,noperm,credentials=/path/to/credentials.txt  0 0
```

Comment: Is `noperm` safe? - The files are based according the _owner_ and _primary group_ and _ugo_ permissions