# Mounting windows share with write permission for both root and user

Tags: mount, windows, remote, cifs, permission-denied

On debian I have write permission for root but not for user. I have not done any changes in smb.conf yet so it is default. Read permission for user is present. How to add write permission for user?

```
gameboy@debian:~$ sudo mount.cifs //MOC/php /home/gameboy/Pulpit/Windows-Share -o user=wat
Password for wat@//MOC/php:  ************* 
gameboy@debian:~$ touch /home/gameboy/Pulpit/Windows-Share/test2
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/gameboy/Pulpit/Windows-Share/test2’: Permission denied
gameboy@debian:~$ sudo -u root touch /home/gameboy/Pulpit/Windows-Share/test2
gameboy@debian:~$ ls -l /home/gameboy/Pulpit/Windows-Share/test2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Apr 26 21:23 /home/gameboy/Pulpit/Windows-Share/test2
gameboy@debian:~$
```

Comment: Related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68081 - and was what I ended up using. (though I didn't need `root` to be able to access - only a different user)

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //MOC/php /home/gameboy/Pulpit/Windows-Share -o user=wat,username=gameboy,password=fakepassword,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

Comment: This works!! After trying so many things, I am glad I found this solution. Thank you