# samba user write error

Tags: mount, samba, readonly

I have an issue when I want to write to a raspberry smb share from my PC (linux mint).

users on the raspberry:
default user "pi" and new user "TF"

"pi" user has write permission, but "TF" does not seem to have it when I mount the shares.

TF was created and added as samba user according to this:

```
sudo adduser TF
sudo adduser TF sudo
sudo adduser TF users #not sure if relevant
sudo smbpasswd -a TF
```

...password also provided, credentials to mount in fstab work well

smb.conf looks like this:

```
[NASHDD1]
   comment = some comment

   path = /mnt/NASHDD1
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   public = no
   create mask=0777
   directory mask=0777
```

ownership of the folders looks like this:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 9 TF root 4096 Oct 13 17:25 NASHDD1


$ ls -l /mnt/NASHDD1/
total 32
drwxrwxrwx 11 TF root  4096 Sep 10 12:22 asusware.arm
drwxrwxrwx  9 TF root  4096 Sep 13 22:35 Folder1
drwxrwxrwx  2 TF root 16384 Jun  9 07:38 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx  2 TF pi    4096 Oct 13 17:25 Music
drwxrwxrwx 10 TF root  4096 Oct 21 21:54 Folder2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your mint pc's directory - in which you mount your pi share properly setup (ownership/flags)?

Comment: I am mounting it to /mnt/nashdd1; 

`$ ls -l /mnt` shows `drwxr-xr-x 2 mymintuser root 4096 okt   21 23:32 nashdd1`

Comment: can you show how your share is mounted in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: That would be `//raspberryPi2/NASHDD1/ /mnt/nashdd1/ cifs credentials=/home/mymintuser/.smbcredentials 0 0` on the client. Interestingly, when I try to create a file or copy one, it will create an empty one and issue an error message after...

Comment: maybe you have to add the `uid`after the .smbcredentials`, uid=TF`. Not sure though.

Comment: did not work :( I am getting really tired of the hardships with samba shares on linux...

Comment: Give NFS a try :) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! However, for NFS, I'll need a radius or some other, not too charming workaround to control access on user level then...

Comment: Check some examples for Samba shares - there're more options, maybe you're missing the `valid users = ` parameter or so. You could add `guest ok = yes` to your smb.conf share - just to see if it's a samba setting/option you're missing - good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/mount-cifs-network-drive-write-permissions-and-chown/68081#68081) post (not enough reputation to upvote there yet).

Mounting cifs via fstab mounted the partition as sudo, therefore I did not have W access. Changing the end of the command to 
`,uid=<user>,gid=<group>   0   0`
solved my mysterious problem!

Answer (score 0):

Listing valid users in a comma separated list is advisable to enabling writeable guest access with 777 permissions.  You may also need wide links enabled depending on how you have the mount point setup.

So, I would first try adding this to your samba share definition:

```
valid users = pi, TF
create mask = 0600
directory mask = 0700
```

If that still doesn't work add wide links:

```
wide links = yes
```

Hopefully this helps. Good luck!