# networkshare Windows >> Linux Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, shared-folders

I'm trying to share a Windows Folder to a Linux machine. I need write-access on Linux.

I shared the folder on Windows permitting 'Full Control' to 'Everyone'.

On MX-Linux, I mounted the shared folder with this command:

```
sudo mount.cifs //WindowsPC/Share /home/geek/Desktop/Windows-Share -o user=geek
```

But I only have read-access.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Aug 11 12:58 'Google Photos'
```

I searched online and found this solution to  [someone with a similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/mount-cifs-network-drive-write-permissions-and-chown)

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

Doing this, the folder gets mounted but is empty.

The Windows Machine is part of Workgroup, not a domain.